# update query to change value for specific row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, row

I am to create A query to calculate the value of a column and update this value to the table. This column is `CAR_PRICE`. 
At the moment the query that I have created updates all the value but all the values in this column become the same. However, my aim is to calculate the value for each specific row.

```
UPDATE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL
    SET CAR_PRICE =
    (SELECT 
        (R.END_DATE-R.START_DATE)*5 AS CAR_PRICE
        FROM CAR_TBL C
        LEFT JOIN
        ROOM_TBL R
        ON C.BOOKING_ID = R.BOOKING_ID
        WHERE C.TICKET_NO = '&TICKET_NO');
```

Is there anyway of amending this query to calculate the value and update a different `CAR_PRICE` for each row in the `CAR_PAYMENT_TBL`?

TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL
(
    TICKET_NO INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CAR_PRICE NUMERIC(5,2) 
);

CREATE TABLE ROOM_TBL
(  
    STAY_NO INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ROOM_NO VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL references ROOM_DETAILS_TBL(ROOM_NO),
    START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    END_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    BOOKING_ID INT NOT NULL references BOOKING_TBL(BOOKING_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CAR_TBL
(
    REG_ID VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TICKET_NO INT NOT NULL references CAR_PAYMENT_TBL(TICKET_NO),
    BOOKING_ID INT NOT NULL references BOOKING_TBL(BOOKING_ID)
);
```

Comment: What do your tables and data look like.  I'm guessing that there is a `CAR_ID` in both `CAR_PAYMENT` and `CAR_TBL` that lets you determine which row from `CAR_TBL` to use.  If the query you posted works, though, that implies that the subquery returns exactly 1 row.  Is your intention perhaps to get rid of the `c.ticket_no` predicate and instead determine which car to use based on the `CAR_ID` from `CAR_PAYMENT`?  Which implies that both `CAR_ID` and `TICKET_NO` are unique keys in `CAR_TBL`?

Comment: @JustinCave I've edited my post and added the table schema. Is it possible for you to provide more information considering the schema that I have provided?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that your subquery returns exactly 1 row for any `ticket_no`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE CAR_PAYMENT_TBL T
    SET CAR_PRICE = (
        SELECT (R.END_DATE-R.START_DATE)*5 AS CAR_PRICE
        FROM CAR_TBL C
        LEFT JOIN ROOM_TBL R
          ON C.BOOKING_ID = R.BOOKING_ID
        WHERE C.TICKET_NO = T.TICKET_NO
    )
    WHERE T.TICKET_NO = '&TICKET_NO';
```